# Does trigger.io support for Windows Phone include control of Live Tiles

Tags: trigger.io

Live Tiles are pretty fundamental to making a Windows Phone app feel native. Maybe we need to wait until we can write our own native extensions. When extension support is available, will it be there for Windows Phone too?

Answer (score 1):

Currently. [No](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/index.html).

If I understand "live tiles" correctly they appear on the start-up screen to display some app information.  Today you'll probably have to "hook" into a remote (ie, json) shared service that both your "live tile" and trigger.io app consume.

Recently I visited the local Microsoft store to "play around" with Windows Phone 7 - bottom line ... trigger.io apps should behave no differently than they do on other platforms (Android & iOS).

And of course, you can still "pin" your trigger.io app to the main screen.